# Why does this valid shell command throw an error in python via subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, shell

The line `awk -F'[][]' '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)` in bash returns my system's current volume (e.g. "97%").

I tried to incorporate this in Python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
command = "awk -F'[][]' '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)"
output = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print(output)
```

However the output from the shell returns

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
b''
```

Why does this fail and how do I fix my code?

Comment: Funny that you tagged this with "bash" but failed to read where the error message came from...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm very new to linux, can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Simple, it was a hint that you should read error messages. Your's for example didn't come from Bash (/bin/bash or /usr/bin/bash) but from /bin/sh, which is a different shell. If you had tried your "valid shell command" (which is a thing that doesn't exist, because there are many shells!) on the shell that reported the failure, you would have been one step closer to understanding the problem and solving it.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought 'sh' and bash were synonymous and assumed it was my implementation with python that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, the syntax you are using is a `bash` syntax (a.k.a. bashism). The **default** shell used in [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is `/bin/sh` & it does not support [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

You can specify the shell to be used via `executable` argument.

Try this:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash").stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using bashism in form of a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), and your `/bin/sh` doesn't support that:

```
<(...)
```

Changing this to a pipe should solve your problem:

```
command = "amixer sget Master | awk -F'[][]' '/dB/ { print $2 }'"
```

Alternative you can start bash from within sh:

```
command = "bash -c 'amixer sget Master | awk -F'\\''[][]'\\'' '\\''/dB/ { print $2 }'\\'''"
```

But as you will soon realize, quoting and escaping will become a nightmare